# Prob. 2 (d), Sec. 27 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Open supersets and ϵ-neighborhoods of compact set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This question concerns exercise 2(d) from section 27 (p.177) in Munkres' Topology:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $X$.
>
> - For any point $x \in X$, we define $$d(x, A) := \inf \{ \ d(x,a) \ \colon \ a \in A \ \}.$$
> - For any $a \in X$, we define
>     $$B_d(a,\epsilon)=\{x\in X:d(x,a)<\epsilon\}.$$
> - For $\epsilon > 0$ we define the *$\epsilon$-neighbourhood* of $A$ in $X$ to be the set $$U (A,\epsilon) := \{ x : d(x,A) < \epsilon \}.$$
>
> ---
>
> - (c) Show that $U(A,\epsilon)=\cup_{a\in A} B_d(a,\epsilon)$.
> - (d) Assume that $A$ is compact; let $U$ be an open set containing $A$. Show that some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $A$ is contained in $U$.

**My effort:**

Consider the map \begin{align}
d(\,\cdot\,,X\setminus U):A&\longrightarrow\mathbb R\\
a&\longmapsto d(a,X\setminus U)
\end{align}
It easy to see that $d(a,X\setminus U)>0$ for all $a\in A$. Since $A$ is compact and the function $d(\,\cdot\,,X\setminus U)$ is continuous, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $$\epsilon=\min_{a\in A}d(a,X\setminus U).$$
Now we will show that $U(A,\epsilon)\subset U$.
From part (c) we have $$U(A,\epsilon)=\bigcup_{a\in A} B_d(a,\epsilon).$$
So we only need to show that $B_d(a,\epsilon)\subset U$ for every $a\in A$.
Let $x\in B_d(a,\epsilon)$. By contradiction, we suppose that $x\notin U$, that is $x\in X\setminus U$, and hence $d(x,X\setminus U)=0$. Then we have
$$d(a,X\setminus U)\le d(a,x)+d(x,X\setminus U)<\epsilon,$$
which contradicts with $\epsilon=\min_{a\in A}d(a,X\setminus U).$ Thus $x$ must be contained in $U$.

That is my proof and I think it is so long. Can someone please offer suggestions for improvement?

Comment: I suppose it should be reasonably obvious, but it would probably be useful if you included a definition of $B_d (a, \epsilon)$ in your post to make sure anyone reading is on the same page.

Comment: To confirm the suspicions of @TheoreticalEconomist, I am familiar with the notation $B(a,\varepsilon)$, but not $B_d(a,\varepsilon)$.

Comment: In the second display, do you mean that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\epsilon = \min_{a\in A} d(a,X\backslash U)$?

Comment: Sorry. There are some typos in the previous versions.

Comment: See [this](http://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-3/section-27-compact-subspaces-of-the-real-line/problem-2-solution/).

Comment: @Aweygan. $B_d(a,e)$ is standard notation, and is usually necessary when discussing more than one metric  space at one time.

Comment: Your proof is correct. It is great, but there is a more direct way of proving this result.

Comment: @Quyle please also view my proof of this very result at the following link. You might also like the more direct approach of mine. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939244/prob-2-d-sec-27-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-if-a-is-compact-and-u-is

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist please have a look at my post on the following link. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939244/prob-2-d-sec-27-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-if-a-is-compact-and-u-is

Answer (score 1):

Suppose by contradiction that no $U(A,\epsilon)$ is a subset of $U.$

For $n\in \mathbb N$ take $a_n\in A$ and $p_n\in B_d(a_n,1/n)$ \ $U.$ Since A is compact we can take a subsequence $(a_{n_i})_i$ of the sequence $(a_n)_n$ with $(a_{n_i})_i$ converging to some $a\in A.$

Now take $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $B_d(a,1/m)\subset U.$  Take any  $n_i>2m$   such that $d(a,a_{n_i})<1/2m .$ Then $$d(a,p_{n_i})\leq d(a,a_{n_i})+d(a_{n_i},p_{n_i})<1/2m+1/n_i<1/m .$$ This implies $p_{n_i}\in B_d(a,1/m)\subset U,$ contrary to $p_{n_i}\not \in U.$

Comment: can you please also take time reviewing my proof of this same result. Here is the link. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939244/prob-2-d-sec-27-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-if-a-is-compact-and-u-is How do you like my proof?